# Makefile filter-out just... isn't working?

Tags: c, makefile, linker

Okay, I'm going to include some backstory about what I'm trying to accomplish, feel free to skip to the end for an example that demonstrates what I'm talking about.

Right at the moment, I'm trying to get a test framework set up around my code, with as minimal of an impact on the actual code base as possible (I'm considering a couple other frameworks right now, and want to make switching as painless as possible). The approach that I'm using currently is to link all of my project's object files together with my testing code so I don't have to `#include` the source files or use some other hack.

This approach creates a problem with the `main` function for obvious reasons; my current plan is to simply not link the object file from my project that defines `main`. This would prevent me from testing it, but it's really simple and any issues will be really obvious, so I'm okay with that. (I'd say this approach beats the alternative of screwing with the symbol table in `main.o`, which is the only alternative I can think of at the moment.)

The issue so far is that I can't seem to get `make` to actually filter out `main.o` from the list of object files I'm linking together, see below.

---

The promised demo of what I'm talking about:

```
MAIN_PROG_OBJ_DIR ::= build/test/release/main-prog-obj
# In the actual Makefile, this is generated as usual
MAIN_PROG_OBJS ::= build/test/release/main-prog-obj/state.o build/test/release/main-prog-obj/main.o build/test/release/main-prog-obj/util.o build/test/release/main-prog-obj/process_args.o

MAIN_O ::= $(MAIN_PROG_OBJ_DIR)"/main.o"
OBJS_FOR_BUILD ::= $(filter-out $(MAIN_O),$(MAIN_PROG_OBJS))

.PHONY: test
test:
        @echo should be removed [$(MAIN_O)]
        @echo OBJS_FOR_BUILD [$(OBJS_FOR_BUILD)]
```

on my system, running this with `make -f testmk test` yields:

```
should be removed [build/test/release/main-prog-obj/main.o]
OBJS_FOR_BUILD [build/test/release/main-prog-obj/state.o build/test/release/main-prog-obj/main.o build/test/release/main-prog-obj/util.o build/test/release/main-prog-obj/process_args.o]
```

Clearly I'm misunderstanding what `$(filter-out`  does/what its syntax is, so how do I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: `"main.o"` --> `main.o` ?

Comment: `MAIN_O` is set to `$(MAIN_PROG_OBJ_DIR)"/main.o"`, which does not match `build/test/release/main-prog-obj/main.o` because the former has quotation marks (which the shell removes when parsing the `echo` command but which remain in the processing done by `make`).

Comment: Ahh, yeah that's it. Thanks everyone lmao

Comment: If either of you care about the rep from an answer, feel free to answer and i'll make it solved/upvote. Since you commented within 5 seconds of each other, I'll just mark whichever is there first as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a quoting issue, `make` was interpreting `"main.o"` literally and therefore wouldn't filter out `main.o` from the list. The confusion came from the fact that, when I echo'd `"main.o"`, the shell parsed the quotes and just passed `main.o` to the echo built-in.

Comment: When debugging `make` files, always, always use `$(info sometext $(somevar))` to be safe from an unwanted layer of interpretation.